# How to set default node shape to box instead of oval?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have some long labels in my graph written in dot language.
As a result, (the default shape being oval) I have some not very practical thin **really long** oval in my graph which take **much** space.

I would like to set the **default** shape to box for all my nodes, unless specified otherwise.

I have seen the `node` notation, but it requires to list any node impacted by the styles.

Is it possible in dot language ?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

using the `node` notation without listing the impacted nodes make the node shape style applied by default.

```
digraph ExampleGraph
{
    node [shape="box"];

    a -> b -> c -> d;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Btw, if you only need to change part of the nodes, you can use a subgraph like this:

```
digraph ExampleGraph
{
  {
    // only change a and d
    node [shape="box"]; a; d;
  }
    a -> b -> c -> d;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for

Comment: This question asks for the **default** node shape, not how to change the shape of a specific node.

Answer (score 6):

Mind that you also can specify default node shape (or any other attribute) on the `dot` tool command line using `-N` switch, e.g.:

```
dot -Nshape=box graph.dot -Tpng -o graph.png
```