# Illegal instruction when changing node shape

Tags: graphviz

I followed the instructions here to change the default node shape: [How to set default node shape to box instead of oval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553273/how-to-set-default-node-shape-to-box-instead-of-oval)

Input file:

```
digraph Blah {
  rankdir="LR"
  node [shape="box"];
  A -> B -> C;
  B -> D;
}
```

I then use the command `dot -v -Txdot gt.dot > gt.xdot`.

Output (verbose):

```
dot - graphviz version 2.44.0 ()
libdir = "/usr/lib/graphviz"
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_core.so.6
Using render: xdot:core
Using device: xdot:xdot:core
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_dot_layout.so.6
Using layout: dot:dot_layout
The plugin configuration file:
        /usr/lib/graphviz/config6
                was successfully loaded.
    render      :  cairo dot dot_json fig json json0 map mp pic pov ps svg tk visio vml xdot xdot_json
    layout      :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp twopi
    textlayout  :  textlayout
    device      :  canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot dot_json eps fig gv imap imap_np ismap json json0 mp pdf pic plain plain-ext png pov ps ps2 svg svgz tk vdx vml vmlz x11 xdot xdot1.2 xdot1.4 xdot_json xlib
    loadimage   :  (lib) eps gif jpe jpeg jpg png ps svg
pack info:
  mode   undefined
  size   0
  flags  0
  margin 8
pack info:
  mode   node
  size   0
  flags  0
fontname: "Times-Roman" resolved to: (ps:pango  FreeSerif,  REGULAR) (PangoCairoFcFont) "FreeSerif, Regular" /root/.fonts/FreeSerif.otf
Illegal instruction
```

But, when I remove the `node [shape="box"];` line, it works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[this file worked correctly on my linux system with two versions of Graphviz]
*You* aren't doing anything wrong, but your font library info may be messed up?
**/root/.fonts** seems like a weird place for fonts.
What is the **-v** output when you use the default node shape?  Does it still reference **/root/.fonts**?

Comment: Yes, it refers to the same location even without the shape change. /root/.fonts is the same as ~/.fonts (as I am the root user), which is one of the standard locations for fontconfig (per https://wiki.debian.org/Fonts#Manually).

Comment: ... and even when the fonts are installed in /usr/share/fonts the same error occurs.